# Teradata not accepting pandas date variable

Tags: python, sql, pandas, teradata, pyodbc

I have date variable in pandas that I would like to pass through a Teradata sql query -

```
import numpy as np
import pyodbc
import time
import os
import teradata as td
from teradata import tdodbc

#create parameters for date
date_from_1 = pd.to_datetime('2021-09-29').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
date_to_1 = pd.to_datetime('2021-10-30').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

#sql query
tran = '''SELECT TRAN.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
                TRAN.DATE
from TRANSACTION TABLE TRAN
where TRAN.DATE >= ?
   AND TRAN.DATE < ?
   '''
pd.read_sql_query(tran, tdp_conn, params = [date_from_1, date_to_1])
```

': ('22008', '[22008] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver][Teradata Database] Invalid date supplied

THANK YOU!

Comment: Why did you convert to datetime and then back to string (which, by the way, will return exactly the string you started with)?  Did you try passing the datetime values directly?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. I used the string to remove the timestamp. Either with or without the string i get the same error.

Comment: It looks like Teradata has some weird date requirements.  What SQL type is the column?   https://docs.teradata.com/r/yxBNqiK9WZh15WoRzMnBrw/bJi1p~ApL7lgY0ZNNEmf_Q

Comment: The date format is correct, seems like the string is not quoted and `2021-09-29` is a calculation resulting in 1983. Try quoting it: `where TRAN.DATE >= DATE ''?'' AND` This also adds the DATE keyword to make it a *date literal* instead of a string.

Comment: Also note `teradata` package has not been actively maintained for several years. Consider `teradatasql` (which does not depend on ODBC / pyodbc) instead.

Comment: thanks. I've tried suggestions and I'm still getting the same error. Unfortunately my company firewall blocks pip and any packages not in Anaconda.org.

Answer (score 0):

FYI to everyone that comes across this in the future, the solution was quite simple actually.

```
tran = """SELECT top 10 TRAN.ACCOUNT_BSB,
                TRAN.ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
                TRAN.PROCESS_DATE
from TRANSACTION_TABLE TRAN
where TRAN.PROCESS_DATE >= cast(? as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
   AND TRAN.PROCESS_DATE < cast(? as date format 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

```
pd.read_sql_query(tran, session, params= [str(date_from),str(date_to)])
```